# BizTalk external assembly namespace and static methods

Tags: static, namespaces, biztalk

Is there some restriction in BizTalk 2006 R2 to accessing static methods in external assemblies when the assembly has a "." in the name ?

I have the solution set-up with the BizTalk project "FooBar", and the external assembly project "FooBar.Helper" (strongly signed and GAC'ed) with a class "Demo" (public and serializable), which is referenced in the BizTalk project

I can create a BizTalk variable of type "FooBar.Helper.Demo" and access an instance method fine, but an expression window the Intellisense shows the FooBar namespace, but if I dot it, I get the error "illegal dotted name" ???

However I can add another project, "ExtComp" with class "Test" and it's static methods are displayed in Intellisense !!!

The only difference I can see is the first external assembly has the dot in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the namespace/name of your helper class... the biztalk project model has several limitations in how namespaces are resolved; so it's easy to break it sometimes. Might be worth a try.